# Spring MVC web app : how to select command objects?

Tags: spring, binding, command

It is a good practice to load as less data as possible from the database through business operations. And sometimes using directly the entity(model) object as the command object is not secure. So what should be the approach on selecting the command object? Using a separate command object for each view does not make sense.

Use cases or a nice resource is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true you may have some security concerns when using domain objects as command objects, Spring tries to bind every single parameter to the command fields, so a user could add extra parameters in the request to modify fields that were not supposed to be bound. In case you go for this approach, make sure to define either a white list or a black list of parameters to be bound:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setAllowedFields("firstName", "lastName");
}
```

or

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setDisallowedFields("id", "creationDate");
}
```

The alternative is to create an extra class for the form. This class can adapt better to the UI needs if your domain objects don't match what you need in the view layer. This class can encapsulate any web logic, validation and the logic to copy to/from a domain object.

So I would say, going for domain objects is fine as long as you set a white / black list and you don't modify it because of UI needs (adding extra fields or extra logic in the domain object), otherwise you should create an additional command object.